# Keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I was working in Eclipse yesterday, when my keyboard shortcuts stopped working. They all worked until yesterday. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> causes a popup saying the cursor does not (yet) have a detectable image. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> works fine, and so does <kbd>Shift</kbd> + a letter. Only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+any key causes this error. Even just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> by itself causes the popup:

[image]

I use Eclipse with the *[Darkest Dark Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme)* plug-in on Windows 10.

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_ filter by `ctrl+shift` and check if a command is bound to _Ctrl+Shift_ only. If there is no command bound to _Ctrl+Shift_, select the _About_ command and in the field _Binding_ press _Ctrl+Shift_ to see if an additional key is recognized.

Comment: There are no keys bound to ctrl+shift. I can press ctrl+shift, the error pops up, then if I hold the keys down and dismiss the error, I can press another key.

Comment: Maybe a key hangs. Did you try to press _Ctrl+Shift_ when the focus is in _Binding_ field in the Keys Properties dialog? What is displayed in the _Binding_ field?

Comment: When I press ctrl+shift in the Binding field, nothing shows. The error pops up, and then ctrl+shift appears in the box.

Comment: The _Binding_ box should show `Ctrl+Shift+` as long as the keys are pressed and should be empty again when the keys are released. Could you share a screenshot of the error dialog that pops up? Is this an Eclipse dialog?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift shows in the box after I have let go of the keys and dismissed the error. https://imagebin.ca/v/3VNS7AoeGAtc

Comment: Strange. I can not find the error text in the source code of Eclipse. So I assume it comes not from the Eclipse platform. Do you have a screen reader, Authohotkey, WindowSpy or similar tool installed on your computer? What happen if you press Ctrl+Shift in a different application than Eclipse? Is your operating system Windows or Linux? Which Eclipse package do you use and do you have additional plug-ins installed?

Comment: I do have ahk, but I don't use it . Ctrl+Shift works in other applications. My operating system is Windows 10. I am using eclipse oxygen and I have darkest dark installed. I will note that depending on where I press control shift (code editor, settings, etc) the bottom message changes.

Comment: If exiting ahk does not help, I recommend to uninstall the _Darkest Dark Theme_ plug-in. This closed source plug-in does load-time weaving to patch Eclipse (instead of contributing their changes to Eclipse) and may have problems with the new version of Eclipse.

Comment: I uninstalled darkest dark and the problem went away. As an experiment, I reinstalled it and the problem still didn't show up. I guess my installation of the plugin became corrupted. Thanks for the help. Would you answer the question so I can mark a correct answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **uninstall** the ***Darkest Dark Theme*** plug-in.

This closed source plug-in does load-time weaving to patch Java bytecode of the Eclipse platform (for legal reasons, to not have to publish their changes). In contrast of using a public API, load-time weaving patches have to be adapted for each (new) Eclipse version: an error in the plug-in can cause strange behavior of the Eclipse platform.

Comment: That is only partially true. Weaving can be very detailed in patching the java bytecode, so it can actually work (and it does) with each new version of Eclipse. It only fails when the patched part of code is different than expected and simply skips the patch in a fail-safe way.

Interestingly the issue user is seeing has nothing to do with weaving. It is simple key listener with an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Piotrek When will a patch be skipped? If the code block, method, class, package, plug-in or all target plug-ins are different? Does the user see if patches have been skipped? If yes, how? Is there any documentation or is this insider knowledge from you as Genuitec employee?

Comment: Howlger, the issue reported above has 0% to do with patching -- none is used. In this case, there is a View that allows you to find icons in the workbench and it was incorrectly binding when the view opened instead of explicit opt-in.  I've covered this below.

Comment: @Tim You already wrote that in your answer. Can you please answer my question when _"fail-safe"_ happens?

Comment: Can you give an example where we've had a bug regarding Eclipse version usage?  For the versions our plugin lists as supporting, we test, period.  That's our job as the vendor of the plugin.  Your response to this post was both unhelpful in answering the actual question and I would consider abusive since it is attacking a software.  Yes, in the holy war of open source vs. closed source, you have taken a side, but it isn't clear to me that this is the forum nor post to relitigate it.

Comment: [That was the original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45436029/1) I was the one who found out that the problem was caused by the _Darkest Dark Theme_. [Please read the _"Be Nice"_ policy (in particular 3., first point)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Could you tell me when _"fail-safe"_ happens?

Comment: RE: "fail-safe", yes, our weavers are written in such a way to minimize negative impact -- we detect structures of classes and ensure we have appropriate weavers for different versions of Eclipse.

RE: "Be Nice" -- I agree.  To be fair, the campaign of saying Darkest Dark is bad for being closed source / using weaving seems to miss the point of the original question.  Not sure what value that added.

Comment: @Tim I never said _"Darkest Dark is bad for being closed source"_. As a developer I write both open and closed source. So the _"fail-safe"_ is per `.class` file, right? Is it displayed to the user when a _"fail-safe"_ happens?

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned by Howlger, yes, Darkest Dark's **Icon Designer** uses Control-Shift when hovering over an icon to allow you to find the icon that you wish to tailor.  This listener only activates if you have the view in your workspace, and I believe only if you have brought the view to the foreground.  That said, we have a change in the next release to explicitly allow you to opt-in to using Control-Shift to find an icon.

[Screenshot of explicit opt-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b65V5.png)

This doesn't specifically have anything to do with open source or otherwise - simply the software behaving as designed

Comment: Thank you for fixing this bug! I enjoy using darkest dark, and am glad that I can use it again. Thanks!

Comment: In the meantime, you can uninstall _just_ the Icon Designer plugin and avoid any complications that the Control Shift keyboard interceptor would have caused.  We've reworked our update site to also move optional components to a different group so fewer people accidentally install the Icon Designer when they don't intend to actually contribute icons.

Comment: Thanks. I’m currently using the darkest dark beta developer thing (not sure what it’s called, I think EclipseDev?) and it works. I really like it so far.

Comment: Is there a reason that a more conventional key binding was not used? Ctrl+Shift on its own collides with, or obscures, quite a lot of actions, doesn't it?