# Eclipse startup ide showing multiple icons

Tags: eclipse

[bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUmiF.png)After eclipse startup, ide multiple "eclipse user storage icon" and "redo" "undo " icons, how to solve it? Please click on the image link at the beginning.

many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try to delete `workbench.xmi` in your workspace-folder under the path `.\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench`. This resets the workbench and the file is generated new.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The workbench.xmi indeed contains those multiple icons. However, after i delete it and restart eclipse again, the new generated workbench.xmi also contains those multiple icons. So I switch to a new workspace, then those multiple icons are gone. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45456044/6505250

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with dozens of User Storage icons.

As suggested by [howlger link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456044/hiding-duplicate-toolbars-items-in-eclipse), you can **modify workbench.xml** (no need to suppress it though, so you avoid a regeneration of workbench.xml), located here: `[eclipse_workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`

I found a repetition of:

```
<children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_IJqhSW9GEeq4uqKh-lBtVA" elementId="org.eclipse.userstorage.accounts" visible="false" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.userstorage.oauth/icons/UserAccount.png" tooltip="Eclipse User Storage" command="_IJuP3W9GEeq4uqKh-lBtVA">
  <persistedState key="IIdentifier" value="org.eclipse.userstorage.oauth/org.eclipse.userstorage.accounts"/>
  <menu xmi:id="_IJqhSm9GEeq4uqKh-lBtVA" elementId="org.eclipse.userstorage.accounts"/>
  <parameters xmi:id="_IJqhS29GEeq4uqKh-lBtVA" name="intoolbar" value="true"/>
</children>
```

- Close Eclipse
- Open workbench.xml
- **Delete the repetitions** (NB: I had to keep 4 repetitions to keep one icon...)
- Reopen Eclipse, the problem should be gone

I also had the problem with the Open Terminal icon, but I think you can easily find the undo/redo icons snippets.

```
<children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_IJrIg29GEeq4uqKh-lBtVA" elementId="org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui.commands.launchToolbar" visible="false" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui/icons/eview16/console_view.png" tooltip="Open a Terminal" command="_IJuNeW9GEeq4uqKh-lBtVA">
  <persistedState key="IIdentifier" value="org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui/org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui.commands.launchToolbar"/>
</children>
```

NB: keeping one repetition for `openterminal` was enough to keep one icon, no idea why it did not work for `userstorage`