# Removing unnecessary icons from STS(Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink, spring-tool-suite

I've just updated my `STS 3.9.0.RELEASE`.

Spring Tool Suite

```
Version: 3.9.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201707061823
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0)
```

After update there are many repeated icons are shown in my `STS`

[image]

How to get rid of these icons??

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45456044/6505250). Could you try to reset the perspective and if this does not help, the solutions given by the answers of the other question?

Comment: It works :) Thanks you genius people