# Eclipse Runtime Invisible Annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, annotations, invisible

My Project files has no Error.But It's keep showing an error massage

> **org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/util/RuntimeInvisibleAnnotationsAttribute**

[image]

can anyone explain this problem?

Comment: This error is not caused by your code, but by an Eclipse plug-in that does not work properly for unknown reasons. Is the [_Darkest Dark Theme_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme) or another Genuitec plug-in installed on your Eclipse IDE (which [might cause this strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456426/6505250))?

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is thrown suggests, that a class file that was read is malformed (=> [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassFormatError.html))