# Eclipse ui glitch and affect other program

Tags: eclipse

I was having this problem a long time ago, i upgraded my computer ram and this program were not appening again, but since a week it has appear again...

Here is an image https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8BU9.png

And it was affecting the "draw" function of my other app like the windows explorer and the task manager. (here are some pics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oChXo.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ubhp.png)

These occure after doing some work on my projects, and after a random time, everything softlock...

I was thinking at a king of graphics card issue, so i tell my computer to select my GTX 1050 instead of the intel integrated one, but i don't fix anything...

Forcing closing eclipse (with the glitched task manager) and re-opening it fix everything, and for the other program affected, that only a graphical issue, wait until (or cause) a next re-draw of the affected task and everything come back to normal.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the plain Eclipse Photon IDE without any installed plug-ins from Genuitec?

Comment: This bug often occur when i use a lot of the Android Andmore plugin to work on my project, i am not sure if letting it sit idle will create the same result

Comment: The screenshot shows that you use at least Genuitec's Darkest Dark Theme. [This plug-in does load-time weaving to "patch" Java bytecode of the Eclipse platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456426). If the issue cannot be reproduced with a plain Eclipse without installed Genuitec plug-ins (not using or disabling is not enough), it is not caused by Eclipse itself.