# Eclipse DevStyle Theme

Tags: linux, eclipse, photon

I installed the DevStyle for Eclipse and menus are bugged. Anybody has an idea of what is going on?

[Workspace Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRjr1.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kc8z.png

Comment: Didn't you already answer the question yourself (_"I installed the DevStyle for Eclipse and menus are bugged."_)?

Comment: @howlger it used to work normal on my other linux installation...

Comment: Okay, so the bug doesn't always occur, but what's your question? If you really want to know what's going on technically, read [my answer and the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45447927).

Comment: @howlger this is the base theme: https://i.imgur.com/dSBqqBH.png. Soon I change for dark theme, it gets bugged: https://i.imgur.com/Tfz1Xkn.png

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the plain Eclipse Photon IDE, without any Genuitec plug-ins being installed using a fresh workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been seen with KDE. Another user posted [a workaround](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/menu-bar-broken/#post-590150) on our forums. The workaround that worked for the developer is:

```
Changing GTK style options in KDE:
System Settings -> Application Style -> GNOME Application Style
I changed GTK2 and GTK3 theme to Breeze-Dark
I then applied the changes and restarted eclipse.
```

This was successfully applied on two machines.